# App crashing [FIRApp appWasConfiguredTwice:usingOptions:]

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

iOS Extension - Fatal Exception: com.firebase.core Default app has already been configured.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RneV.png)

Comment: Can you post the code where and how you are configuring?

Answer (score 1):

From the message it is clear that `FIRApp's` configure function is called twice by your app. It is supposed to call once. The best place to call it, is in the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` in your `AppDelegate`.

In order to identify from where it is being called you can use 2 approaches.

1. Press `CMD + Shift + F` and search for `configure` keyword and identify from the results.
2. Add a symbolic break point and app will pause when configure function get called. See the screenshots below:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]